# Merge meta-tags "user", "users", and "user-accounts"

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, retag-request

We have three closely related tags on meta: [user](/questions/tagged/user), [users](/questions/tagged/users), and [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts).

We're not talking about a lot of posts here, but from what I could all be handled with a single tag.

Please merge [user](/questions/tagged/user) and [users](/questions/tagged/users) into [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) and leave synonyms behind.

Comment: `user` and `users` definitely don't need to exist separately, but I could kind of see a reason to keep `user-accounts` separate for concerns specific to accounts and account management (whereas `users` could also refer to, e.g., the behavior of a user or something of that sort). I could go either way on that one if others have any thoughts regarding it.

Comment: I can see that. Cleaning up questions tagged with `user-accounts` may leave the tag empty, though, which is why I suggested it. For what it's worth, MSO has `user-accounts` separate from `users`, although the tag wiki of the latter seems to conflate it with the former. `user` is a synonym for `users`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged [user](/questions/tagged/user) into [users](/questions/tagged/users) and made the former a synonym of the latter. I'm going to leave [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) separate for now and we can revisit it later if needed.